# Cyrillic (Bulgarian) spellchecker for Texmaker

Tags: spelling

I'm using Texmaker under Windows and I need spellchecker for the bulgarian language. Any ideas ?

Comment: Texmaker uses the openoffice 2.x dictionaries.  So search for these on the internet, download to the correct texmaker folder and follow the directions in the texmaker user manual to connect to the desired dictionary.

Comment: I downloaded the three files bulgarian.aff, bulgarian.dic and bulgarian.txt from https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries and put them into the TeX Maker folder and it worked!